# Dynamically edited cell value in Handsontable is empty

Tags: handsontable

I apologize if my question was already answered but I didn’t find any relevant answer.
I would like to dynamically edit cell value therefore I used:

```
var setButton = document.getElementById('setButton');
setButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {        
    hot.getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
    hot.render();
})
```

it edits cell but I don’t see original value, only empty.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/janzitniak/qdg420v8/6/

Note: Please select to any cell and then click to *Set value to selected cell* button.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

Long story short: Call `enableFullEditMode()` before you call `beginEditing()`.
Not sure about the `render()` call though - I think that call can be removed.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpen8oLg/)

#### Storytime

I was looking for a solution to a similar problem, and had to look into the code to figure it out. In hindsight this was straightforward.

- First there is [some code](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/8b6e9c404ac0aa4fb211a6bedbd68b7fbd81c658/src/editors/textEditor/textEditor.js#L195) which will reset the content of textareas to an empty string, to work with IME (or at least the comment says so)
- And then there is [code](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/8b6e9c404ac0aa4fb211a6bedbd68b7fbd81c658/src/editors/baseEditor/baseEditor.js#L241) which will only set the original value into the cell, when the full editor mode is enabled.

Comment: Thank you @seasick for your time and right answer!